# PHP : refresh a page with GET parameters without scrolling

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, firefox, refresh

My problem seems pretty easy but I'm kinda new to web programming, so here it is :

I want my button to refresh the page, pass some GET parameters to trigger a PHP action and I don't want the screen to scroll on top of the page.

What I'm using at the moment is a mix of ajax and javascript, it does what I want but it's not reliable. Here's what I remember of the code (I don't have the code at hand)

```
<?php
echo '
    <span href="$.ajax(\''.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?do=dosomestuff\'); setTimeout(function(){windows.location.reload()},100);)> ... </span>';
?>
```

I have three issues with this implementation :

1. I feel it's overkill to use ajax when a href would maybe do the job
2. A friend of mine tested it and he got the firefox pop up ("*To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier*") everytime he hits the button. I read it comes from POST data passing, but I only use GET data.
3. On some computers, the button doesn't work everytime. It's random, maybe the delay is not big enough. How big can the delay be so that I'm 100% positive it will work everytime but at the same time it's not noticeable for the user ?

Thank you for your help and advices !

Edit : following Tularis' advice, here's the code I came up with, but I can't manage to make it work

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['do']) and $_GET['do'] == 'swap')
{
    rename('img1.jpg', 'img3.jpg');
    rename('img2.jpg', 'img1.jpg');
    rename('img3.jpg', 'img2.jpg');
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $("#spanLink").click(function() {
        $.ajax('<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?do=swap');
   });
});
</script>
</head><body>
<img src="img1.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="cat">
<img src="img2.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="dog">
<span style="cursor:hand;" id="spanLink">Some text to click</span>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't combine html-links with javascript inside them. That's bad form (and leads to exactly the problem you're having). Instead I suggest using jQuery and linking the onClick event handler to the span element like so:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $.('#spanLink').click(function() {
      $.ajax('<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?do=somestuff');
   });
});
</script>
</head><body>
<span id="spanLink">Some text to click</span>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still can't manage to make it work. I updated my code.

Comment: what exactly are you still missing? When I test the code, clicking the text runs the PHP script (and thus renames the files). Is it supposed to do anything else ?

Comment: Clicking the text doesn't run the PHP script in my case (in both IE and Chrome). I can see the request in the "Network" panel of the Chrome debugger, but it's like the parameters are not passed. I just noticed that if my url is /project/imgswap.php, then clicking the text doesn't work. HOWEVER, if the url is /project/imgswap.php?do=swap, then clicking the text works. Any idea why ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use ajax and jQuery where you can easily get the new content and update it anywhere you want in page without reloading the complete page.